# How to setup VMware Tanzu TAS on Azure to deploy .Net 4.5 application

Tags: azure, .net-4.5, vmware, tanzu-application-service

I am new to Azure and TAS (https://tanzu.vmware.com/application-service)  and want to deploy .Net 4.5 web form application using VMWare Tanzu TAS (previously Cloud Foundry)  on Azure.

I got Azure trial subscription to try it out but could not any details references for proceeding with the setup and installation.

https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/vmware-inc.vmware_tanzu?ocid=GTMRewards_WhatsNewBlog_azure_purview_Vol177&tab=Overview&exp=ubp8

If anyone has experience it before or any reference to start with, it would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Using [VMWare Tanzu](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pas-windows)

[image]

2. Go to VMware Tanzu Network.
3. And download the **VMware Tanzu Application Service**.
4. And download the  **Windows FS Injector**  tool for your workstation OS.
5. Add the Windows Server container base image to the product file

````
```
winfs-injector ^
  --input-tile PASW-DOWNLOAD-PATH ^
  --output-tile PASW-IMPORTABLE-PATH

```

Where:

-   `PASW-DOWNLOAD-PATH`  is the path and filename to the TAS for VMs [Windows] product file you downloaded.
-   `PASW-IMPORTABLE-PATH`  is the desired output path for the importable product file.  
    For example:
    
    C:\Users\admin> winfs-injector ^
    --input-tile c:\temp\pas-windows-2.9.0-build.1.pivotal ^
    --output-tile c:\temp\pas-windows-2.9.0-build.1-INJECTED.pivotal
````

7. Go to the Ops Manager Installation Dashboard and then click on **Import a Product**.
8. And to add the TAS for VMs [Windows] tile to the  **Import a Product** product list, select the path  `PASW-IMPORTABLE-PATH`  file from your workstation.
9. To add the TAS for VMs [Windows] tile to your staging area, click  **+**  under the  **VMware Tanzu Application Service for VMs [Windows]**  product listing.
10. Once the VM is configured

**Deploying .Net Apps**

The cf CLI command  `cf push`  pushes apps to TAS for VMs. There are two main ways to run the  `cf push`  command:

- Run  `cf push APP-NAME`  to push an app the easiest way, using default settings.
- Run the  `cf push`  command with flags and helper files to customize.

**Default settings:**

1. Choose a name for the app.

   - The app name must be unique.

     - Apps running at their default routes need unique names as the default routes are based on app names.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   cf push APP-NAME
   ```

   Where  `APP-NAME`  is the name of the app.

#### Default Route

- **Hostname**: The name of the app is the one specified in the  `cf push`  command.
- **Domain**: The default apps domain for the TAS for VMs installation.

For eg;- An app named  `my-app-xyz`  running on TAS for VMs with an apps domain  `apps.example.com`  would, by default, run at the URL  `https://my-app-xyz.apps.example.com`.

From azure portal

1. Choose the VMware Tanzu based on your plan and subscription.

[image]

[image]

And push your .Net code to Git and from Git you deploy to Tanzu using power shell commands as mentioned above. And for more information please follow the references.

Thanks @Tanzu docs

References taken from
[Deploying .NET Apps | VMware Tanzu Docs (pivotal.io)](https://docs.pivotal.io/application-service/2-13/windows/develop.html)